# 5D Autofocus - disable tracking after lock?

Tags: lens, autofocus, manual-focus, canon-5d-mark-iii

I recently got a 5Dmk3 and it's been a really fun toy so far. I'm coming from a Canon 7D, so I'm trying to adjust to the much more complicated autofocus system. I've read the manual and looked around online, but nothing has pointed me to the answer of this just yet.

Is it possible to disable autofocus tracking after a focus lock is acheived? I want to be able to use the manual focus override, but the autofocus tries to track when I do this, so I end up fighting it and I really hate the feeling of spinning the focus wheel while it's trying to move on its own accord!

My lens is a 35mm f/1.4 L, if that affects anything here (the autofocus zones per lens guide in the manual just about blew my mind)

Comment: Basically, all the autofocus zones per lens guide does is tell you that the camera automatically turns off focus points that require a wider aperture than the maximum aperture of the lens connected to the camera. If you are using an f/4 lens, none of the AF points that require an f/2.8 lens will be active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have *AI Servo* selected for the AF mode. The behavior you describe is normal if that is the case.

**To do what you want, you need to select *One Shot* as the AF Mode.**

Please note that when shooting in one of the continuous drive (burst) modes, the camera will not refocus between each shot that is taken while you continue to hold the shutter button all of the way down. To focus again, you need to completely release the shutter button and then half press it again.